# Did the Prophet dispatch aid for Mecca during a drought?

Tags: source-identification, seerah

I heard in a sermon that Mecca was hit with either drought or famine while it was still under the control of the pagans. When it happened, the Prophet sent relief aid for the people of Mecca in the form of 500 gold coins.

Can somebody identify a source for this? Any details on the time and context in which this occurred will also be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't find any such a statement or source and I'm afraid that without any additional information it would be hard to find anything like this. Why should he prophet () send 500 dinars to the pagans as an aid, when it seems more appropriate to send them food?